# Highcharts JS - heatmap set gridLineWidth

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have a question about the heatmap from Highchart JS (again). I want to set borderWidth of the heatmap, i mean the gridLines inside the heatmap.

Currently i can set without and with gridLines but only complete (horizontal and vertical). 
I would like to set only horizontal and on other hand only vertical gridLines.

I don't find any property which allows to set only x (horizontal) or only y (vertical).

The only property i found is :

```
  'borderWidth': 1,
```

Here's a jsFiddle:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z6vLt9jg/)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to go with the axis

```
min : 0,
max : 1,
gridZIndex : 10,
gridLineWidth : 1,
```

Take a look at this, maybe you find out, how to make it work as you want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/u765vneL/